# VHDL: nth digit of decimal integer

Tags: vhdl

I have an integer signal (range 0 to 9999). I’m trying to display it on set of 7-segment displays. I have implemented multiplexer (one digit is displayed at once). Now I need to split my integer into single digits.

Theoretically it is very simple: just use mod (ex NUM / 100 mod 10 gives second digit). Problem is that when I’ve compiled solution with mod (used 4 times) my code used over 9000 cells just for mod.  That is too much (but works).

Then I tried casting to smaller integer, but it doesn’t work. Integer range 0 to 9 uses 4 bits so it is really range 0 to 15.

I’m sure there is simpler on obvious solution but I wasn’t able to find it. Please note that I’m beginner :).

EDIT: the code:

This part sets proper output to display for given digit

```
process (clk)
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        case number1 is
            -- od prawej: a b c d e f g
            when 0 => segment <="1000000";  -- '0'
            when 1 => segment <="1111001";  -- '1'
            when 2 => segment <="0100100";  -- '2'
            when 3 => segment <="0110000";  -- '3'
            when 4 => segment <="0011001";  -- '4'
            when 5 => segment <="0010010";  -- '5'
            when 6 => segment <="0000010";  -- '6'
            when 7 => segment <="1111000";  -- '7'
            when 8 => segment <="0000000";  -- '8'
            when 9 => segment <="0010000";  -- '9'
            when others=> segment <="1111111";  
        end case;
    end if;
end process;
```

This part selects display (1 of 4) and sets digit value

```
process (clk)
variable count: integer range 0 to 1000;
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        if count = 1000 - 1 then
            count := 0;
            case digit is
                when "1000" => digit <="0001"; number1 <= year/1000 mod 10;
                when "0001" => digit <="0010"; number1 <= year/100 mod 10;
                when "0010" => digit <="0100"; number1 <= year/10 mod 10;
                when "0100" => digit <="1000"; number1 <= year mod 10;
                when others => digit <="0001"; 
            end case;
        else
            count := count + 1;
        end if;

    end if;
end process;
```

Comment: post some, code its been a while since i worked with vhdl, and  had a school assignment with this, maybe i can see what happens

Comment: The first question is : how is your integer signal coded? Is it a VHDL "integer" or some other representation?

Comment: I think [this](http://www.jjmk.dk/MMMI/Lessons/06_Arithmetics/No6_Conversion/Index.htm) will help.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when a number needs to be represented in decimal form, the coding of choice for the number is Binary Coded Decimal (BCD), in which each digit of a base-10 number is encoded using 4 Bits of binary.

Of course this means that you will not be able to treat the entire number as one binary integer, since each 4-bit digit has a valid range of only 0-9 (A-F are illegal). Thus the decimal value 12 would be encoded as "0001 0010".

Instead of simply adding two VHDL unsigned values (or std_logic_vectors), any operations you make on the number (generally addition and subtraction) must use logic tailored for BCD. There are plenty of online resources available with examples (search for BCD adder, for example), so I won't go into any more detail here.